# At what point does a question about game hardware become off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94868/how-can-i-connect-a-5-1-4-floppy-drive-to-my-modern-pc) (and answer) about connecting a 5 1/4" floppy drive to a computer and was directed to post this question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/513887/how-do-i-connect-a-5-1-4-floppy-drive-to-a-modern-pc) where it has clearly been accepted as on topic.  The relationship to this question being about games is obviously a personal one (the disks I'm looking to read are old computer games).  My question is about future [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility) questions, at what point do they become off topic?

Comment: A good acid test is to take your question, and remove games (and/or gaming hardware) from it.  If the problem still remains, it's not a good fit for Arqade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just my two cents: your question has nothing directly to do with gaming, or more relevantly, hardware *directly* related to playing video games. There is nothing about trying to use a 5 1/4" floppy disk that is directly related to playing games except for your intent.

In general, if we want any questions at all in the [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility) tags, we would want them to be specific to gaming hardware because then the question is directly related to the site topic and is the kind of knowledge one might expect a gaming expert to have.

Comment: Interesting, would you feel the same way if the question had been about making a floppy disk work on a [dedicated game system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64_peripherals#Floppy_disk_drives)?  which in my case it was not.

Comment: I probably would be more likely to accept a question like that.

Comment: @Jason that'd be in keeping with his we handle such things now. We allow fairly detailed tech questions about, say, PS3 hardware, but not standard PC hardware.